# How to iterate through an array in AngularJs and print the values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am bring a data from a server which is an Array that hold a long and string value.The data i recieve is mentioned below

```
warehouseList: Array[2]
0: Array[2]0: 11: "Enterprise"
1: Array[2]0: 21: "800-BETHLEHEM"
```

How to print the names in the div.

```
<ng-repeat "items in warehouseList">
{{item[1}}
```

Please provide some idea. Thanks .

Comment: Did you reference or copy `warehouseList` in your controller's `$scope`?

Answer (score 0):

if you have some object which stored in array for example

```
var arr = [{someKey:'value',someOtherKey:'otherValue'},{someKey:'value',someOtherKey:'otherValue'}]
```

then you can access like this

```
<div ng-repeat "item in arr ">
    {{item.someKey}} 

</div>
```

Comment: No, its not working, i have tried the conventional or the usual way. its not working.

Comment: could you post your array ?

Comment: i have posted it in my question . I initialise in the scope like this $scope.carrierWarehouseList:[{}],

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in warehouseList">
    {{item[1]}}
</div>
```